# Razor view with asp.net core not working

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm still trying to get my head around asp.net core so this may be a stupid question but I can't get a razor view to work with asp.net core mvc.

I'm getting a 500 error when I'm trying to return a view and not getting anything useful in the console logging.

My project.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.1"
        },
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "1.0.0",

        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor": "1.0.1",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0"
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace aspnetcoreapp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace aspnetcoreapp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Debug);

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
            routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.Run(context =>
            {
                return context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello from ASP.NET Core!");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Home.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
//using System.Text.Encodings.Web;

namespace MvcMovie.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // 
        // GET: /HelloWorld/

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // 
        // GET: /HelloWorld/Welcome/ 

        public string Welcome()
        {
            return "This is the home Welcome action method...";
        }
    }
}
```

and I have a basic view in /Views/Home/Index.cshtml

any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how annoying.

after hours of head banging, then posting the question, on my "one last go" I found the answer.

after debugging in VSCode i was able to get the actual error message.

then I found [Internal Server Error while running a simple .Net Core MVC application on Ubuntu 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38135016/internal-server-error-while-running-a-simple-net-core-mvc-application-on-ubuntu) and this had the answer.

time to go and try and find out what "preserveCompilationContext" actually does now.

thanks